# Teradata - return column position/order

Tags: teradata

How can I return the position or order of a column? Such as, column ABC is column number 2, and PK_DEF is column number 1.

I checked in the column views but couldn't find anything about position or order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the same order like in the DDL, you have to use ColumnID from dbc.columns[v]. The ColumnID exactly has this purpose and is unique per databasename/schema.

```
ORDER BY Databasename, Tablename, ColumnID
```

Answer (score 0):

I was provided the answer on the Teradata Support site, and added this to my DBC.COLUMNSV query:

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DatabaseName, TableName ORDER BY ColumnId)

Comment: This is just going to assign a number based on the alphabetical order of the columns within a table, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Andrew, Yes it was what I wanted. I had to create a query for a data dictionary and was requested to add column order.